# Cannot get Eclipse to recognize Sony Xperia under Linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I have Sony Xperia ZL and I would like to develop an app for it. I created a new project with the android adt bundle downloaded from the webpage (latest one) and just want it to compile the empty project to see if it would show. However the Android Device Chooser shows only ???? in the Serial Number and cannot recognize any other info.

Here is what I have done:
I have activated developer options (on MTC mode)
I have created a udev rule that reads like this: 
    ariel@ColoAsus:~$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="054c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
I have started and killed the adb server multiple times 
I have run adb devices and this is the output:

List of devices attached 
EP7328Z0B7      device

I have also enabled usb debugging in the phone. Android version is 4.2.2 and my operating system is Debian.

Can any one tell what might be wrong?

Comment: I've connected really lots of phones to my Linux (Mint) development machine but I had never created a udev rule. Try to reboot the phone...

Comment: I shut down eclipse. The disconnected my phone. I shut it down. I turned it back on again then connected it. Turned on eclipse and nothing changed. Thanks for the try. I also have a Motorola Xoom and did not have to create a udev rule for it. But I tried everything I could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddling, it turns out that the USB connectivity mode is at fault. My phone was set to MSC (Mass Storage Mode), I had to turn it to MTP (Media Transfer Mode) in order for Eclipse to recongnize it properly. The udev rule is probably unnecessary.